# TEXTJOIN of INDEX MATCH unique values if value on another table is contained in a cell

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, textjoin, excel-tables

On cell B5 I'm trying to get a TEXTJOIN with delimiter "," of INDEX MATCH to the price range you see on Table B. Because cell A5 contains "Apple" then "$$$" is one of the values I need, also A5 contains "Banana" then "$$" is the second value i need. Finally cell A5 contains "Pineapple" but because "$$$" is already was selected because of apple then no need to add it again.

Any help will be much appreciated.
[image]

What would I do if instead of 1 cell like A5, I will have multiple rows like this:
[image]

What would I do if I have a SKU that has only some of the Fruits and I have to use the formula based on the SKU?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Excel 365, you can do:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",", 1, UNIQUE( XLOOKUP( FILTERXML( "<m><s>" & SUBSTITUTE( [@Fruits], "|", "</s><s>" ) & "</s></m>", "//s" ),
                                   TableB[Fruit], TableB[Price Range],0)) )
```

[image]

Comment: If it is truly a range (e.g. from $$ to $$$) then the answer is different and a little messy. It is also possible to do with with a lower version of Excel, but messy.

Comment: the formula above worked, amazing. thanks!

Comment: Mark I've edited my question to include a case where instead of 1 cell like A5, I will have multiple rows, would you know the solution to this as well?

Comment: Hi @Kobe2424 - sure, it's a simple change. You can simply remove the `@` from the formula so that it will evaluate the whole column. This would support concatenated entries mixed with single entries - like this: `=TEXTJOIN(",", 1, UNIQUE( XLOOKUP( FILTERXML( "<m><s>" & SUBSTITUTE( [Fruits], "|", "</s><s>" ) & "</s></m>", "//s" ),
 TableB[Fruit], TableB[Price Range],0)) )`. If you will never have concatenated entries, then the formula can be a lot simpler - like this: `=TEXTJOIN(",", 1, UNIQUE( XLOOKUP( [Fruits], TableB[Fruit], TableB[Price Range],0)) )`. Let me know if that does not work.

Comment: Works. Thank you once again!

Comment: mark I've added one more scenario I will love to use your help once again. What would I do if I have a SKU that has only some of the Fruits and I have to use the formula based on the SKU? (I've edited the original post with another image 3rd scenario)

Comment: Hey @Kobe2424! When I get a break, I can propose a way. Basically, I think it would be best to wrap `[Fruits]` in a FILTER that filters them according to each SKU, so it is probably `=TEXTJOIN(",", 1, UNIQUE( XLOOKUP( FILTER( [Fruits],[SKU] = [@SKU] ), TableB[Fruit], TableB[Price Range],0)) )`, but I have not tested it.

Comment: thank you mark once again. I opened a thread for this one and someone answered. I appreciate your time and effort